# Pass structures between contracts with Solidity 0.5

Tags: contract-design, solidity, solidity-0.5.x

I'm trying to pass an instance of the `Storage` structure from StorageController.sol to Publisher.sol. No matter what I do, I get `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` in my Truffle test.

Both contracts have `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` at the top. StorageController.sol is imported by Publisher.

Here's what I tried so far:
 1. Using a mapping:
StorageController:

```
mapping(uint256 => Storage) public storages;
```

Publisher:

```
Storage memory _storage = _storages.storages(storage_id);
```

This won't even compile, it says, `TypeError: Different number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (6).`

2. Using a function

StorageController:

```
    function getStorage(uint256 i) external view returns(Storage memory) {
        return storages[i];
    }
```

Publisher

```
StorageController.Storage memory _storage = _storages.getStorage(storage_id);
```

Output: `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

3. Passing a tuple

StorageController:

```
    function getStorageData(uint256 i) external view 
        returns(bytes32 name, uint256 maxLength, uint256 rank, uint256 writingFee, uint256 sellPrice, bool nonpublic) {
        return ("", 1,1,1,1,false);
    }
```

(I hardcoded the output values just in case)

Publisher:

```
(bytes32 name,,,,,) = _storages.getStorageData(storage_id);
```

Output: same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are getting this error because your `Publisher` contract doesn't know about `StorageController` contract after deployment.

I have written 2 working contracts.

**StorageController contract**

```
contract StorageController {
    struct Storage {
        string name;
        uint256 maxLength;
        uint256 rank;
        uint256 writingFee;
        uint256 sellPrice;
        bool nonpublic;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Storage) public storages;
    uint storageCount = 0;

    constructor() public {
        Storage memory newStorage = Storage({
            name: 'aaa',
            maxLength: 11,
            rank: 12,
            writingFee: 13,
            sellPrice: 14,
            nonpublic: false
        });

        storages[storageCount++] = newStorage;
    }

    function getStorageData(uint256 i) external view 
        returns(string memory name, uint256 maxLength, uint256 rank, uint256 writingFee, uint256 sellPrice, bool nonpublic) {
        return (storages[i].name, storages[i].maxLength,storages[i].rank,storages[i].writingFee,storages[i].sellPrice,storages[i].nonpublic);
    }
}
```

**Publisher contract**

```
contract Publisher {
    StorageController _storages;

    constructor(address storageControllerAddress) public {
        _storages = StorageController(storageControllerAddress);
    }

    function getStorage(uint index) public view returns(string memory, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, bool) {
        (string memory name, uint256 maxLength, uint256 rank, uint256 writingFee, uint256 sellPrice,bool nonpublic) = _storages.getStorageData(index);
        return (name, maxLength,rank,writingFee,sellPrice,nonpublic);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. solidity 0.5.4 compiler was used and you don't need `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`
2. `StorageController` contract was deployed first. Then its address was used to deploy `Publisher` contract.

Comment: Spot on! I had an error in my deployment script, and the _storage reference was not initialized.

Comment: I could also pass a Storage instance between the contracts using a function that returns Storage: ` function getStorage(uint index) public view returns (Storage)`. However, using a public mapping still doesn't work in 0.5.4.